# Background image not showing on Flask template

Tags: flask, jinja2, pythonanywhere

I am a Flask, Pythonanywhere, HTML/CSS beginner. I am trying to get a background image on the template but it's not showing up.

My site is arranged as follows:

> / > home > user> mysite > static >background
>
> / > home > user> mysite >template >thet.html
>
> / > home > user> mysite > mainthing.py

On my template I've tried the following code samples and yet these yielded no result:

```
<body background='/home/user/mysite/static/background.png'>

<body background="{{ url_for('/home/user/mysite/static', filename='background.png') }}">
```

This problem seems to be happening on my local machine too even though when I open the html template on Dream Weaver, it opens up fine. Just not on the web browser.

I tried the suggestions here: [jinja2 set background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023107/jinja2-set-background-image)

The url_for is giving me an internal server error while body background isn't displaying the background.

Comment: What template engine are you using?

Comment: Jinja2 is what Flask uses?

Comment: url_for takes a function name and is not relevant here. you need to setup static file configs on the pythonanywhere webapps tab to serve static files from /static/. and then the url should be something like `/static/background.png`, and is not related to your homedir/path on pythonanywhere at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Conrad. I learned from my mistake

Answer (score 2):

You can link static files like this `url_for('static', filename='background.png')`([Flask doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#static-files))

Comment: That's exactly what I tried. It's giving me an internal server error. (See code sample above)

Comment: `url_for('/home/user/mysite/static', filename='background.png')` is not exactly the same. You are pointing the `static` direcotry on your computer rather than saying to flask to use the `static` folder of the project.

Comment: Your code sample does not match this answer. `url_for` wants the name of an endpoint (e.g., `static`), not a path to a folder.

Comment: By default Flask adds an endpoint for serving static content with name "static"([doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/))