# Jinja doesn't display the background image only for one page

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am creating Python/Flask blog and used a Bootstrap template for my front-end. I have a block which remains on each page the same, and the next block(block main) which changes depending on the content. For each of the pages, the background image I set for my static block displays correctly, except one page.

The app structure is the following:
1. Main page with all the posts/articles
2. Separate pages for each posts' topic
3. A page for the specific post which you choose to read about

The issue appears, when I load the page with the post to read it. The background image for the static block disappears.
When I check the logs, I can see that the code tries to add the link to the background image to the URL of my page and that's why it can't find the picture. How can I make it read my background image link independently of the page URL?

**Logs error:**
[image]

**HTML**

```
    <header class="masthead" style="background-image:url('static/images/cloud-main.jpg')">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
          <div class="site-heading">
            <h1>Clean Blog</h1>
            <span class="subheading">A Blog Theme by Start Bootstrap</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

**Routes**

```
@app.route('/<topic>/<int:post_id>', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def post(topic, post_id):
    """
    :param post_id:
    :return: Specific post you clicked in the feed + comments to it
    """

    # Retreive the post user clicked at by receiving its id. post_id retrieves from 'history' page
    current_post = models.Post.query.filter_by(post_id=post_id).first()

    #Retreive all comments related to the current_post
    comments = current_post.comments

    comment_form = forms.NewComment()

    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        if comment_form.validate_on_submit():

            new_comment = comment_form.get_comment(post_id)
            current_post.add_comment(new_comment)
            flask_login.current_user.add_comment(new_comment)

        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('post', topic=topic, post_id=post_id))

    return flask.render_template('post.jin', topic=topic, post=current_post, comments=comments, form=comment_form)
```

I checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023107/jinja2-set-background-image) but it didn't help me. I think the problem is different here.

Thank you!

Comment: I've actually not seen `url({{'static/images/cloud-main.jpg'}})` before and it doesn't appear to be in [the docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/urlprocessors/). Can you please point me to where you found that? Separately, try `style="background-image: {{ url_for('static', filename='images/cloud-main.jpg') }}">`

Comment: Actually, I don't follow it at all. I thought maybe you'd ported it over from Django but it doesn't look valid in that templating language, either. Is `url` a function you have defined yourself and injected into jinja with `app.jinja_env.globals.update()`?

Comment: it's Flask, not Django. I edited the  ```url({{'...'}})``` line in my example above (it was just a test)  - doesn't work for the post page.

I've also already tried ```url_for``` but it didn't help

Comment: I know that it's Flask. I'm trying to work out where you got `url({{...}})` from. Also, you haven't explained what went wrong with `url_for` and I'm not convinced that you implemented it as I suggested